# Float выводит некорректное значение

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Пишу на Java такой код:

```
float pi = 3.1415926f;
System.out.println(pi);
```

Выводит: 3.1415925. Я знаю, что у чисел с плавающей точкой вычисления неточные, но тут же присвоение числа. При этом если дать значение на 1 больше или меньше, то всё корректно выводится. Объясните нубу, пожалуйста, почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что вы записываете число в десятичной системе счисления, а компьютер хранит числа с плавающей точкой в двоичной системе с ограниченным количеством знаков в мантиссе, и тождественность результатов не гарантируется.

Десятичное число преобразуется в двоичное число с плавающей точкой в экспоненциальном нормализованном виде. Для этого оно раскладывается по двоичным разрядам.

3.1415926<sub>10</sub> = 0011.0001 0100 0001 0101 1001 0010 0110<sub>2</sub>

Конечной десятичной дроби в другой системе счисления может соответствовать бесконечная (иногда периодическая) дробь. Бесконечную дробь не получится записать в двоичном формате без потери точности.

При выводе производится обратное преобразование.

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей принято использовать готовую переменную класса Math. Вывести её можно таким образом:

```
System.out.println(Math.PI);
```

Результат будет такой, который вам нужен.
А конкретно о вашем случае, если хотите разобраться почитайте [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/).

Answer (score 1):

zenden2k, это двоично-десятичное представление числа, оно здесь вообще ни при чем. В компьютерах используется стандарт IEEE 754. Вот про него статья: http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754.html. По поводу, почему получается 3.1415925, а не 3.1415926 - потому, что ты урезаешь экспоненту. Т.е. сначала берешь число double(64 бита) = 3.1415926000000000684053702571 (в двоичном = 01000000 00001001 00100001 11111011 01001101 00010010 11011000 01001010) и урезаешь ему экспоненту до float(32 бита) = 3.141592502593994140625 (в двоичном = 01000000 01001001 00001111 11011010). Вот и получаешь такую погрешность. Все претензии к ассоциации IEEE :)

Comment: Ну ведь первопричина в том, что производится преобразование, а не в том, что обрезается экспонента или мантисса. Сначала яйца, потом курица.