# Почему 0.3 != 0.1+0.2?

Tags: javascript, float

Почему не виполняетса условие

```js
if(0.3 == 0.1+0.2){
  document.write('yes')
}else{
  document.write('no')
}
```

Comment: Потому что так устроены числа с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Потому что 0.1+0.2 = 0.30000000000000004 подробнее например тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441918/float-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/441945#441945

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/number#неточные-вычисления