# вычитание float из float. C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public float delaytime = 0;
private void Update() {
    if (delaytime >= 0.1f && t){
        Invoke ("time", 0.1f);
        t = false;
    }
}

void time() {
    Debug.Log(delaytime-0.1f);
    delaytime -= 0.1f;
    txt.text = "Cooldown: " + delaytime.ToString();
    if (delaytime >= 0.1f)
        Invoke ("time", 0.1f);
    else
        t = true;
}
```

в другом методе в delaytime устанавливаю значение 2f

получается какой-то бред или как это еще назвать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Суть проблемы не ясна

Comment: [Float выводит некорректное значение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441918/float-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - ответ для java, но суть та же самая, погрешности из-за разных систем счисления. Для хранения десятичных чисел используйте decimal.

Comment: Округлять надо: `Debug.Log((delaytime - 0.1f).ToString("F1"));` или так `Debug.Log($"{delaytime - 0.1f:F1}");`